# CakePhp 2.3: Losing GET Parameters on pagination links

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I have a url like this:

> http://url.com/catname/city?bedroom_no_min=2&price=1&sort=price&direction=desc&city=57&cati=i0

my pagination links looks like this:

> http://url.com/catname/city?page=2&sort=price&direction=desc

Please notice that the get parameters

- page
- sort
- direction

are kept, but lost are

- bedroom_no_min
- price
- cati

For me it looks like the typically cake-ish parameters are kept, but mine are lost.

Is there a way to tell the pagination which parameters it should accept and use?

Comment: In your controller, are you setting the Paginator->settings[paramType] to "querystring"?

Comment: Yes, correct. This is requested due seo optimizing.